# Finding the transformation matrix $T$ so $T^{-1}AT$ will be diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 3 &  1 & -1 \\
-1 &  1 &  1 \\
 2 &  2 &  0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

For this matrix, I have found eigenvalues of $2$ and $0$ and eigenvectors of 
$$
e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
e_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

How do I find a matrix $T$ such that $T^{-1}AT$ is diagonal from these eigenvectors?

Comment: I edited your question to show you how MathJax formatting is used on this site.  Please look at the code and use it in the future.  Here's a tutorial:  math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: **If** the eigenspace for either eigenvalue $2$ or $0$ is two-dimensional (is spanned by **two** linearly independent vectors), then you can form the columns of $T$ from the three vectors.  **If not,** then your task is impossible (i.e. $A$ is not similar to a diagonal matrix).

Comment: It is possible to find an eigenvector $v$ associated to $2$ such that $\{v, e_2\}$ is a linearly independent set. Find $v$.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and directing me to a link on how to correctly type in problems.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and directing me to correct formatting. I forgot to mention that the eigenvalue of 2 is repeating. Does this mean the matrix T is  matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: The matrix $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is not invertible, since the columns are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

An $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  I see that you found one eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda =2$. However, I suggest that the **eigenspace** of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $\lambda =2$ is two-dimensional.

Recall that one way to find the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is to find the vectors $x$ which satisfy $(A- \lambda I)x=0$. Now $$(A- 2I)=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\\2&2&-2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ This row-reduces to $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Now the dimension of the **eigenspace** of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to the dimension of the **nullspace** of $(A-\lambda I)$, which is $2$. So if $$x= \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix},$$ our system of equations that satisfies $(A-2I)x=0$ is $x_1+x_2-x_3 =0$. You found that one combination that satisfies that equation is $$x= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Another one is $$x = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ These are your eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda =2$. Note that these vectors are linearly independent. Therefore they span a two-dimensional eigenspace.

Use these along with a correct eigenvalue for $\lambda =0$ to form the columns of your diagonalizing matrix. (Check your $e_0$).